# What is the relation of Yogi with God?

Tags: gods, bhakti, yoga-sutras

He cannot expect protection as compared to a Devotee?
Given he achieves things by ego-effort the personal safety should also be his own responsibility.

Comment: Yogi is someone who has perfectly made a union of himself with god i.e., he realized the god within himself. Devotee (or Bhakti) is where you are limited and you have to devote yourself to a deity. So it is not quite clear what you are asking - relation between bhakt bhagwaan, or Yogi (as you have tagged yoga-sutras too).

Comment: Perfect union is a realization stage. I mean how he manages worldly matters and physical safety specifically. For a Devotee (Bhakt is a special case of a Devotee) there is no question of safety or anything. Because everything is surrendered to the will of God. As a result he expects and receives some level of care. For Yogi it is different, because he achieves things by personal conscious effort. Thus  - I suppose - he can expect less regarding how the world behaves to him.

Comment: You are misunderstanding a lot of things in a single place. Bhakt is NOT a special case of devotee. Devotee means the one who *devotes* himself to some other entity. In that case, you must understand that the body neither belongs to you, nor the world. You sacrifice bodily maintainance and karma in the world for that external entity. The path of self-realization is for advanced people - those who realize that the supreme is inside them. They realize their true self and perform their bodily duties in the world, knowing he's independent of both - body and world. This is yoga.